# Dealing with explicit parameters required by inner implicit parameter lists

Tags: scala, implicit

I'm currently working with a codebase that requires an explicit parameter to have implicit scope for parts of its implementation:

```
class UsesAkka(system: ActorSystem) {
   implicit val systemImplicit = system

   // code using implicit ActorSystem ...
}
```

I have two questions:

1. Is there a neater way to 'promote' an explicit parameter to implicit
   scope without affecting the signature of the class?
2. Is the general recommendation to commit to *always* importing certain types through implicit parameter lists, like `ActorSystem` for an Akka application?

Semantically speaking, I feel there's a case where one type's explicit dependency may be another type's implicit dependency, but flipping the `implicit` switch appears to have a systemic effect on the entire codebase.

Comment: It seems to be that having `system: ActorSystem` **not** be an implicit doesn't have any benefit. You can always override an implicit parameter. For your questions, I would say **no** and **maybe**.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make `systemImplicit` private ?

```
class UsesAkka(system: ActorSystem) {
   private implicit val systemImplicit = system
// ^^^^^^^

   // ...
}
```

This way, you would not change the signature of `UsesAkka`.

Comment: I would have preferred to only make a comment, but I don't have enough reputation yet... Just hope that this answers your first question.

Comment: +1 an improvement on my original approach, but everything in the original question still stands :)